# How to prevent other workers from accessing a message which is being currently processed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, message-queue, amazon-sqs

I am working on a project that will require multiple workers to access the same queue to get information about a file which they will manipulate.  Files are ranging from size, from mere megabytes to hundreds of gigabytes.  For this reason, a visibility timeout doesn't seem to make sense because I cannot be certain how long it will take.  I have though of a couple of ways but if there is a better way, please let me know.

1. The message is deleted from the original queue and put into a
   ‘waiting’ queue. When the program finished processing the file, it
   deletes it, otherwise the message is deleted from the queue and put
   back into the original queue.
2. The message id is checked with a database. If the message id is
   found, it is ignored. Otherwise the program starts processing the
   message and inserts the message id into the database.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the default-provided SQS timeout but take advantage of `ChangeMessageVisibility`.

You can specify the timeout in several ways:

- When the queue is created (default timeout)
- When the message is retrieved
- By having the worker **call back to SQS and extend the timeout**

If you are worried that you do not know the appropriate processing time, use a **default value** that is good for most situations, but don't make it so big that things become unnecessarily delayed.

Then, modify your workers to **make a `ChangeMessageVisiblity` call to SQS periodically to extend the timeout**. If a worker dies, the message stops being extended and it will reappear on the queue to be processed by another worker.

See: [`MessageVisibility` documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ChangeMessageVisibility.html)